# Plot two graphs using plotly package in same plot in R

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

How can I plot both the graphs in same window ?

```
library(shiny)

library(plotly)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
today <- Sys.Date()
tm1 <- c(2,3,5,7,9)
tm2 <- c(3,4,6,8,9)
x1 <- today + tm1
x2 <- today + tm2
y1 <- rnorm(length(x1))
y2 <- rnorm(length(x2))
output$p <- renderPlot( plot_ly(x = ~x1, y = ~y1, text = paste(tm1), mode = 'markers'))
output$p1 <- renderPlot ( plot_ly(x = ~x1, y = ~y2,text = paste(tm2, "days  today"), mode = 'markers', color = '4'))

})
```

Comment: what means in the same window? in one plot? or in two div in screen? add code of you UI

Comment: in one plot only.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use subplots for achieve your goal. They are explained here: https://plot.ly/r/subplots/

The code of the first example is that:

```
library(plotly)
p1 <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~unemploy) %>%
  add_lines(name = ~"unemploy")
p2 <- plot_ly(economics, x = ~date, y = ~uempmed) %>%
  add_lines(name = ~"uempmed")
p <- subplot(p1, p2)

# Create a shareable link to your chart
# Set up API credentials: https://plot.ly/r/getting-started
chart_link <- plotly_POST(p, filename = "subplot/basic")
chart_link
```

Hope it helps:-)